# How to put spool mode off in tpt export?

Tags: teradata

I am trying to switch off spool mode in tpt export. Unfortunately I am not able to identify the option to do so. I am new to teradata. Can anyone please help.
I saw one option in the internet , Spoolmode NOSPOOL. But not sure how to use it in the tpt export script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do this

```
VARCHAR SpoolMode      = 'NOSPOOL'
```

Answer (score 0):

If by spool you mean not spooling the data and output you can try bteq:

```
bteq << EOF >/dev/null
.sessions 16
.logon $TDSRV/$TDUSER,$TDPASSWD

.EXPORT FILE = $OUTPUT_DIR/$OUTPUT_FILE;
.SET WIDTH 12000
.SET TITLEDASHES OFF

SELECT * FROM TABLE;

.LOGOFF
.EXIT
EOF
```

Comment: No. I am looking for Spoolmode NOSpool option in tpt export.